# The relation between JPA respository configuration and entity scan

Tags: jpa, repository, spring-data-jpa

I defined the below repository:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long>
```

Where the **Product** class is an entity (annotated with **@Entity**).
Why do I need also the **@EntityScan** annotation in my project to scan for entities?
If I won't use this annotation the **ProductRepository** won't recognize the **Product** as entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entities don't exist just by themselves. They live as a whole and form a graph of interconnected entities.

The JPA provider must know all the entities at startup to extract all the needed metadata, check that all the dependencies are present (i.e. if A has an association with B, but B isn't found, there is a problem), validate the named queries, etc. That means that, to create the EntityManagerFactory, you need to provide all the entities that the application will use. EntityScan is used to find them in the classpath.